# website redirections different from .htaccess configuration

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, web, redirect

I have web page created in Wordpress v5.4, Theme Twenty Twelve and just installed SSL certificate.

I want to have such redirection structure (redirection codes in rectangles), to optimize for SEO:

[image]

but according to Google Chrome Site Inspector I have the follwing one:

[image]

So the schema is not fully optimized as for two cases there are dwo cascade redirections whereas should be one.

What is weird, current schema doesn't reflect .htaccess file. My .htaccess file looks as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

So, my understanding of the code is that if url is typed in without https://, script rewrites it into version with https:// an nothing else, so there must be another place where other redirections (e.g. with www -> without www) are being made.

I have checked index.php - no redirections.

I also checked additional lines in .htaccess file don't overwrite those "hidden" ones, so if I simply add them I got multiple redirections error in web browser.

Could you please advise me what else should I do to get desired structure of redirections?

Answer (score 1):

First rule redirect all www to https://domainname.com/, second all http to https://domainname.com/, one hop

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://domainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://domainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thank you @JarekBaran, your solutions works fine for me, now  all redirections are done with one hop

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing the redirect from www to non-www is due to the address you’ve set in your settings (WordPress dashboard → Settings → General).

For the redirect you want to achieve, you have to add rewrite conditions for the `www.` in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you over-engineer, I modified .htaccess as you suggested. Now it's bettet, however there's stil one more chained redirection: http://www -> https://www -> https://[nowww (301->301->200) - Just for te clarification, should I change also in Wordpress settings you mentioned to get full result?